# What is $f$? Finding where a function converges pointwise?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, convergence-divergence

I have a question.

> Let $f_n(x) = x^{4n} + \frac1{n^2}$. AS $n \to \infty$, $f_n$ converges pointwise to a function $f$ on $[0,1]$
>
> What is $f$?

Now if I am understanding correctly, couldn't $f$ be many things? Since we have $[0,1]$ wouldn't it be correct to say that $f = 1$, since $f_n(x) = 1^{4n} + 0 = 1$ That gives point-wise convergence right? What about $f(x) = x$ this should give uniform convergence on $[0,1]$ to $0$ right? But I need pointwise convergence, so I suppose I need to choose some value $[0,1]$

Also, is there a way to disable the automatic rendering below(the one that shows my $LaTeX$ rendered? It is lagging this old laptop to a crawl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $x<1$, the value for $x^{4n}+\frac1{n^2}$ as $n$ increases without bound is $0+0$. The first $0$ is because large powers of $x$ approach $0$.

When $x=1$, the value for $x^{4n}+\frac1{n^2}$ as $n$ increases without bound is $1+0$.

Thus, on $[0,1]$, $f_n$ approaches a step function: its pointwise limit is $0$ on $[0,1)$ and $1$ at $x=1$.

Comment: If I have $p$ as a fixed arbitrary value with $0 \lt p \lt 1$ and need to show that $f_n \to f$ on $[0,p)$, I have $[0,1)$ which is less than one, but what can I set $p$ to here, I know it is *just* barely less than 1, but how can I represent that outside of interval notation? $0.999999\lt P \lt 1$

Comment: @Examin5days, $[0,1)$ means the interval $[0,1]$ except for the single point $1$. That's the interval on which $f_n\to0$.

Comment: How can I show with Mathematical rigour that it converges to $0$ in $[0,1)$, I can see that it does logically, but is there a method I should be using? (I can just ask this as a new question if I am taking up too much of your time)

Comment: @Examin5days, you can ask it as a new question, but, briefly, show that every interval around $0$ contains a tail of the sequence $f_n(x)$ ($\forall x\in[0,1)$) i.e. that no matter how small a positive number $\varepsilon$ you pick, you can find some large $m$ such that $f_n(x)<\varepsilon\quad\forall n>m$.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure where along the line the confusion is coming in, but it is pretty clear that you need a bit of clarification on what it means for $f_n \to f$ pointwise. This means that $f$ is a (actually the, if it exists) function such that fixing any $x$ in the domain, $f(x) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$. For example in the example given $f(1) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} 1^{4n} + \frac{1}{n^2} = 1$. Whereas $f(0)= \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} 0^{4n} + \frac{1}{n^2} = 0 $

In summary, if $f_n \to f$ pointwise, then this simply means $f(x)$ is the limit of the sequence of values $f_n(x)$.

Comment: This makes perfect sense. I wasn't sure what sort of answer they were seeking, given that I have never done a problem like this. Mainly I think I was thrown off by seeing $f$ by itself rather than attached to $(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

For all $x$, as $n \rightarrow \infty$, $\frac{1}{n^2} \rightarrow 0$, so we can just focus on the $x^{4n}$ part.

If $x < 1$, then as $n \rightarrow \infty$, $x^{4n} \rightarrow 0$. But if $x = 1$, then $x^{4n} = 1$ for all $n$. So the pointwise limit of the $f_n$ is the function

$f(x) = \begin{cases} 
      0 & x \ne 1 \\
      1 & x = 1
   \end{cases}
$

Comment: I don't see what this adds to my preexisting answer. (Half-kidding. I know you didn't see mine before posting yours, as mine predated yours by merely eleven seconds; so I'm not suggesting you should not have posted your answer. That said, now that you have seen mine, might I suggest deletion as a duplicate?)

Comment: I see no harm in multiple answers - the asker is free to refer to whichever has a wording that is most useful to him/her

Comment: Fair enough. Hopefully they'll both help future readers, as well.

Comment: @msh210 I would argue that this answer has a gentler layout, given the piecewise function shown above. 

One query, is it correct to say that I have uniform convergence on interval $[0,1)$ or does this not follow the definition of uniform convergence correctly?

Comment: You wouldn't have uniform convergence. For example, given $1 > \epsilon > 0$, in order to have uniform convergence, we would need $x^{4n} < \epsilon$ for all $n$ sufficiently large, and for all $x$. But if you choose $x > \sqrt[4n]{\epsilon}$, you wouldn't have this, and $\sqrt[4n]{\epsilon} < 1$ for all $n$, so this is possible.